# String array return Null in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I was making this app with a Column that contain a picture on top and text on the bottom.

For my pictures , I looped it and it starts from 1 , so I wanted to have text under the Images to follow the index too. I have 5 pictures , and here is my code :

```
child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 20, 0),
                            child: Card(
                              semanticContainer: true,
                              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                              child: Container(
                                width: 380,
                                height: 250,
                                color: Colors.blue,
                                child: Image.asset(
                                  "assets/Planes/$i.jpg",
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                ),
                              ),
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                              ),
                              elevation: 5,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(planeName.toString()),
                        ],
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

I have my code for the **planeName** array above the **singleChildScrollView**:

```
var planeName = <String>[
  planeName[1] = "a",
  planeName[2] = "b",
  planeName[3] = "c",
  planeName[4] = "d",
  planeName[5] = "e",
];
```

But when I run the app , all it return is null :

[image: The problem]

I need help to make the text under the picture into a, b, c, d, e following the index of the pictures.

Any answer is appreciated , thank you !!

Comment: Change from `Text(planeName.toString())` to `Text(planeName[i])`

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change your list to

```
List<String> planeName = <String>[
  "a",
  "b",
  "c",
  "d",
  "e",
];
```

and in your `SingleChildScrollView`,

change

```
Text(planeName.toString()),
```

to

```
Text(planeName[i-1]),
```